# Proxy API call then redirect to Angular app using Nginx

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

Supose you visit this url:

`https://example.com/AbCDeFghijK`

...you wait a few milliseconds while `AbCDeFghijK` is verified by an API, then you are redirected to:

`https://example.com/?ref=SomeString`

How could you achieve that if you're using **Nginx** to serve an Angular App?

The idea is to achieve something like [producthunt](http://www.producthunt.com/) does when you click a link but using the same domain. I haven't figure it out how to get this done without using a [MEAN](http://meanjs.org/) app or [another view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) in my Angular App.

---

**Additional info**

When you make a GET request to `https://api.example.com/t/AbCDeFghijK`, you'll receive a redirect to `https://example.com/?ref=SomeString`.

And, when you make a GET resquest to `https://example.com`, you're accesing to an Angular app served by **Nginx**.

```
server {

  server_name my-angular-app;

  root /path/to/my-angular-app;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: really not clear what the exact behavior you are looking for is. Stay in angular app or load angular app if logged in?

Comment: @charlietfl, I'd like to load an angular app after receive a response from `https://example.com/AbCDeFghijK`

Comment: so is this an ajax request? still not clear what the flow is

Comment: @charlietfl, It's a GET request to `api.example.com/t/:id` and the result will be a redirect to `example.com/?ref=SomeString`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this problem would be to first store the URL and then make an AJAX call in the background to verify the URL and then redirect the user based on the response.

```
var proxy = "https://api.example.com/t/";
var payload = $location.path();
$http.post(proxy + payload).
  success(function(data, status) {
    if(data.ref) return $location.path('/?ref=' + payload);
  }).
  error(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data,status);
  }
});
```

Here, you would want to perform some validation on the payload that you are extracting from the path to ensure that it's within your schema before making the call to your API.